# wget имена для файлов из списка

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Имеется файл со списком ссылок для скачивания:

```
ИМЯ_1 УРЛ_1
ИМЯ_2 УРЛ_2
...........
ИМЯ_N УРЛ_N
```

как через wget можно закачать файлы с новым именем?

нашел решение тут https://toster.ru/q/139001 но почему-то не могу исполнить данный скрипт на debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам надо сформировать и выполнить команды вида `wget -O имя_н урл_н`:

```
$ cat файл | while read n l; do wget -O $n $l; done
```

---

для проверки правильности, чтобы не производить само скачивание, вставьте `echo` между `do` и `wget` — команды будут просто выведены на экран:

```
$ cat файл | while read n l; do echo wget -O $n $l; done
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался, файл со списком был некорректно составлен. Все работает

Comment: Регистр опций важен! `-o` задаёт имя файла для лога, `-O` - для сохранения скачиваемого файла под другим именем.

Comment: @sercxjo, спасибо за внимательность. действительно, так и есть. память подвела.

Comment: @aXXy, в ответе была ошибка. должна быть опция `-O`, а не `-o`

Comment: да, опции свои использовал

Comment: @alexander barakin Подскажите, если мне нужно дополнить WGET параметрами "-P /folder" и "-t 2" , то как правильно вставить их в ваш код. Спасибо

Comment: @Новичок, то, что вы написали, является опциями, а не параметрами. опции для **любой** программы должны быть указаны после имени программы. а параметры, кстати, указываются уже после опций.

Comment: @alexander barakin Я пробовал указать после программы, ничего не вышло, делал так :      $ cat файл | while read n l; do wget -t 2 -P /folder -O $n $l; done

Comment: @Новичок, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.