# WGET скачивание файлов по списку с перименовыванием

Tags: bash, wget

Есть тхт файл со ссылками для скачки.

В списке имена некоторых файлов повторяются, но это разные файлы, а wget идя по списку когда доходит до файла с названием уже присутствующим в папке скачанных думает что это один и тот же файл и скачивает его переименовывая (добавляя цифру к расширению файла: file.jpg1, file.jpg2, file.png1 и тд.)  тем самым меняя расширение файла, а если использовать -nc ,то wget просто не качает такой файл, думая что файл уже скачан

Подскажите как сделать чтобы расширение не менялось, а менялось либо название файла, либо еще как-то? Иначе не могу потом использовать по назначению файлы с измененным расширением

Спасибо

Comment: нашел решение здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561190/wget-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -nc -i list.txt
```

При запуске Wget без параметров -N, -nc, или -r загрузка одного и того же файла в одну папку приведет к созданию копии файла с именем file.1. Если существует файл и с таким именем, третья копия будет называться file.2 и т.д. При параметре -nc будут выводиться предупреждения об этом.

Comment: Не точно написал, простите. Внес правки в вопрос